# Performance difference under Windows Server with two identical applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I have two dedicated servers running Windows Server 2016. Both are for shared hosting of websites (developed in ASP NET MVC / Framework 4.8 and hosted via IIS). All the websites run correctly on the two dedicated servers, there are no problems. I also have several more recent Windows servers.

As far as the hardware is concerned, it's identical:

- Intel Xeon E3-1270
- 64 GB RAM
- 512GB SSD
- 1 GBPS UP / DOWN

However, the two servers offer very different performance levels when it comes to starting up a site or loading a page for the first time. We can call A the 'fast' server and we can call B the 'slow' server. When the page has already been loaded once, performance is identical.

Here are some observations:

- Server A starts the application in less than a minute, whereas server B always starts the application in almost 3 minutes.
- If I take the application from server B and migrate it to server A, it will be fast whereas it was slow on server B, so I conclude that the problem is not the application (we have a standard application whose modules are the same on every website on every server).
- The CPU is less hard-working on server B than on server A, which is very strange because it's the fastest server...
- I've looked at all the configurations in IIS but I can't find any difference that could explain this difference in performance.
- An even stranger fact is that the busiest server is the fastest...

1. Could the problem be linked to a cache system with a different configuration?
2. How could I find the configuration or the problem to explain these two differences in performance?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Startup performance could very easily depend on configuration or versions of some component of the software stack. It might be useful to run the application on a fresh install (on a vm) to establish a base-line performance.

Comment: you can check the server load, make sure caching is enabled, compression is enabled. enable iis failed request tracing.use some performance profiling tools like PerfView to analyze the performance of your applications on both servers. These tools can help identify performance bottlenecks and provide insights into the root cause of the performance differences.